# gmaps4rails data string, loading markers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I would like to take an array and load the data into the json object, but i am stuck on exactly how to do it.

TripsController

```
def index
@trips = Trip.all
@markers = Array.new
@trips.each do |trip|
  for marker in trip.markers
    @markers.push(marker)
  end
end

@gmaps_options =
{
  "markers"     => { "data" => '[{ "lng": "-99.9018131", "lat": "31.9685988"},
                                 { "lng": "-102.552784", "lat": "23.634501"},
                                 { "lng": "-122.3667", "lat": "40.5833"},
                                 { "lng": "-121.8356", "lat": "39.7400"}
                                  ]', },
  "polylines"   => { "data" => ' [ [
                     {"lng": -99.9018131, "lat": 31.9685988},
                     {"lng": -102.552784, "lat": 23.634501},
                     ], [
                      { "lng": "-122.3667", "lat": "40.5833"},
                      { "lng": "-121.8356", "lat": "39.7400"}
                      ] ]' }
}

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @trips }
  end 
end
```

The longitude and latitude are hardcoded right now but i would like to load the @markers into the longitude latitude,

```
"lng": @markers[0].longitude, "lat": @markers[0].latitude
```

This whole data object is a single string.  I would have to add

```
"lng": + "@markers[0].longitude" + , "lat": + "@markers[0].latitude"
```

for every marker object, so in some hackey way make a whole string in a for loop.
I am thinking there has to be a better way.

In the view the map is called with gmaps(@gmaps_options)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder), which is included by default in later versions of rails.  There's a list of similar projects at the end of that page too.  On a side note, do you know about [string interpolation](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex6.html)? (Sorry, no time for a more detailed answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what all you have in your application, but from the controller code it looks like you have model Trip with association `has_many :markers`

and Marker model have latitude and longitude fields.

and also you want to display all those associated markers.

Now to display the pins on google-map it requires proper activerecord-relation records

so one-way to do is

CONTROLLER:

```
@trips = Trip.pluck(:id)
@markers = Marker.where("trip_id in (?)", @trips)
@gmaps_options = @markers.to_gmaps4rails
```

VIEW:

```
= gmaps("markers" => { data: @gmaps_options })
```

Another way is:

form the json string of the all location's latitude and longitude with the help of loop and pass that string to data in view, as you have done above, because `.to_gmaps4rails` does not accept array.

Hope this would help you.

Thanks.

Comment: I used your answer in my code, it worked great. I answered this question with the code.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code working for polylines with gmaps4rails

```
def index
@trips = Trip.all
@tripLocation = Trip.pluck(:id)
@markers = Marker.where("trip_id in (?)", @tripLocation)
@gmaps_options = @markers.to_gmaps4rails

@polylines_json = {}
polylines = []

i = 0;
@trips.each do |trip|
  polylines[i] = []
  trip.markers.each do |marker|
    polylines[i] += [{:lng=>marker.longitude.to_f, :lat=>marker.latitude.to_f}]
  end
  i+=1
end

@polylines_json = polylines.to_json

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @trips }
end
end

def show
@trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
@markers = @trip.markers
@gmaps_options = @markers.to_gmaps4rails

@polylines_json = {}
polylines = [] 
polylines[0] = []
  @trip.markers.each do |marker|
    polylines[0] += [{:lng=>marker.longitude.to_f, :lat=>marker.latitude.to_f}]
  end


@polylines_json = polylines.to_json

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @trip }
end
end
```